# How can I identify a Azure Pipelines environment by environnment variable?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Does [Azue Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/index?view=vsts) provide an environment variable in CI jobs to allow it's identification like e.g. [Travis does with `TRAVIS`](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables#default-environment-variables)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called "Predefined build variables", the variables give you a convenient way to get key bits of data into various parts of your build pipeline. This is the comprehensive list of predefined build variables.

You can find the variables list [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts).

There are also predefined variables to the release pipeline, you can find them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch).

In case a script runs in build it may get the [system environment variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts#system-variables) `TF_BUILD` which will be set to `True`.

Comment: How can I get env vars in a script running in a linux vm image?

Comment: For example: `echo "Read variable $Build_BuildId"` it's will print the value of the build id.

Comment: Sry, not specific enough: How can I get the env vars into Python script/code in a linux vm image? E.g. `os.getenv(` should work as usual, right?

Comment: It's like every environment variable.

Comment: Syntax was not clear to me first. Alright, "Build.BuildId" gets `Build_BuildId`.

Comment: `TF_BUILD` would be a more robust choice than `Build_BuildId` I guess...

Comment: If you want only to know if the script runs in build so you right :)